# Multitenant application with single app service and multiple databases for each client

Tags: blazor, multi-tenant

I am trying to implement a multitenant blazor application architecture with single app service and multiple database. Each unique database for single client and I want to apply authentication using following technique :

Master Database (Only I have access using Master Application to manage)

1. IP Address for each client in whitelist to prevent public access.
2. Based on IP Address connect to client specific database and URL.
3. Client specific database connection username and password string stored in Azure Key Vault.
4. Application license validation through Master Database (using IP Address and URL) as well to disallow access when license expired.

Client Application:

1. When first loads retrieves username and password based on IP address and URL.
2. Validates license based on IP Address and URL.
3. Connects to database and perform normally.

How can I achieve the above scenario ? If there is any better and efficient way please advise for my scenario ?

I have tried using multitenant application with multiple app services.